# Chrome question any way of inputting text into this textbox?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
<div class="_3rB8s"><div class="kpO1d _15T4F"><div class="_1MR7J"><div class="b39iZ"><div class="_2INCN">Your message...</div><div class="_2MprQ"><div class="jxro6"><div class="DraftEditor-root"><div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer"><div aria-describedby="placeholder-53p98" class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;"><div data-contents="true"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="53p98" data-offset-key="dpa79-0-0"><div data-offset-key="dpa79-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="dpa79-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="_3ZArC"><button class="_3wxIK"><svg width="20" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 18" class="GIQX4"><path d="M.843 17.25L20.082 9 .843.75l-.01 6.417L14.583 9 .833 10.833z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></button></div></div></div>
```

this is how it looks if i dont input anything into it

and this is how it looks after i input manually "test" into it, it morphs somehow or maybe im wrong

```
<div class="_3rB8s"><div class="kpO1d _15T4F"><div class="_1MR7J"><div class="b39iZ"><div class="_2MprQ"><div class="jxro6"><div class="DraftEditor-root"><div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer"><div aria-describedby="placeholder-53p98" class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;"><div data-contents="true"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="53p98" data-offset-key="dpa79-0-0"><div data-offset-key="dpa79-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="dpa79-0-0"><span data-text="true">test</span></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="_3ZArC"><button class="_3wxIK"><svg width="20" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 18" class="GIQX4"><path d="M.843 17.25L20.082 9 .843.75l-.01 6.417L14.583 9 .833 10.833z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></button></div></div></div>
```

I have no idea how to go with this one :\ I'm very new to making chrome extensions but please help me I'm stuck I've been stuck on this for the past weekend, after I write something the class "_2INCN" disappears, if I click on it and I'm "focused" in the textbox the class becomes "_2INCN _449op", and after I write something in it the class disappears altogether.

Comment: there's no "textbox" in that HTML

Comment: So what do I do?? there is a textbox heres an image of it https://i.imgur.com/zH3xssK.png | class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" role = textbox.. thjere is a textbox sir

Comment: Oh, right, `contenteditable` - it's hard to see details of code when it's one long line like that - so, what does all that HTML have to do with the tags `javascript` or `google-chrome-extension`?

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry but like i said im a complete newbie i made an extension that auto clicks on a ready button (it's a matchmaking service) and i want to input some text in a textbox to inform people which maps to ban automatically so i dont have to waste time doing it myself each time, but I have no idea what I'm doing frankly speaking, all I know for now is how to set an interval and click buttons, so not much to go with... I put the tags that I thought would be relevant, the extension is mostly a javascript background.js file thats why the tags are like that